# Generation of default values for multiple dependent input combinations

Tags: c#, default-value

I have a c# program in development which requires a large number of input variables from the user (32 at the current count, but increasing) .These are either entered directly into the interface, or loaded from a pre-made xml file

In many cases the user will not know (or care) about the values of some of these variables - They may just want to enter some simple dimensions and get a generic answer based on some internal assumptions, without having to know every detail of the design.

The unknown variables can be derived either from default values, or in many cases from relationships to known variables (sometimes both, with one alternative being preferable IF the other required values are known)

The question is how best to handle the decision tree to take an unknown value and  assess which values are available to fill in the gaps?

As an example: take three variables: A, B, C

We know A = B + C (Where C is typically around 75% of A)

If we know all 3 values, GREAT (But we should probably check it satisfies the original rule and the values are actually valid)
If one value is missing we can work it out from the other 2 (but we should check the other 2 DO exist first)
If 2 values are missing we can use the 75% relationship to fill in the gaps
If all 3 values are missing, we can set a default value for one of them and work upwards from there.

To date I have been handling this with a series of methods containing 'If' checks but this gets out of control FAST with more than 2 relations and its highly dependant on the order each variable is checked within in the code rather than any kind of internal hierachy of importance which is making maintenance a problem as the code expands.

```
static class defaultValue
{
    public static double a(InputValues inputvalues)
    {
        double x;
        if (inputvalues.a != 0) x = inputvalues.a;
        else {
            if ((inputvalues.b != 0) && (inputvalues.c != 0))
            {
                x = publicProgramValues.b + publicProgramValues.c;
            }
            if ((inputvalues.b = 0) && (inputvalues.c != 0))
            {
                x = publicProgramValues.c/0.75;
            }
            if ((inputvalues.b !=  0) && (inputvalues.c = 0))
            {
                x = publicProgramValues.b / 0.25;
            }
            if ((inputvalues.b = 0) && (inputvalues.c = 0))
            {
                x = 100;
            }

        }
        return x;
    }
}
```

As you can see from the very simplified example above the code is already beginning to get out of hand with a relatively simple relationship and I haven't begun to handle the checking of the other 2 variables yet.

A more complex example (and closer in reality to the problem I face) would be an object 'rectangle' with the properties 'height', 'width', 'area', 'aspect ratio'. Given any 2 known values the unknowns can always be calculated but I make it around 15 combinations of possible inputs with which you could achieve this at which point the code starts getting pretty messy, especially when 'Height' might also be linked to some other set of variables... my brain has melted.

Im sure theres a more elegant way to handle this - Id love to hear some suggestions?!

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to say without knowing domain area and problems your are solving. Sometime it is better to re-think design from scratch.

Possible solutions:

- you can encapsulate your logic for calculating default values to the class `InputValues` (or some proxy class).
  If properties are not read very often and performance is not the top priority, you can put logic to the getter of a property. In this case you will always see how default is calculated and once you add a new property you always add a logic for how to calculate default value.
- encapsulate the logic to a particular class that is constructed from parameters. For example if you construct a `Rectangle` object from your `InputValues` then logic of calculation default values can be encapsulated there.
- create some T4 template and use it to generate a class with default logic calculation. In this case you will have huge class but it will be simple to maintain it via the template.

Comment: Thankyou for the response - I appreciate that I have been vague about the context, but suffice it to say that im describing dimensions and attributes of physical objects, so I think the 'rectangle' example is valid without being unnecessarily complex.

Comment: Then one of proposed methods may help you to simplify maintenance of your classes

Comment: Your first two examples seem to address where to put the logic to define default values, which is currently not an issue. Im sure I could use some improvements here but my current solution is functional. 

My question really was: How to describe the logic itself.

I am interested in your template suggestion as this is new to me - I will investigate that further to see if it fits my needs.